# How to add empty space at the end of string?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I got `let str = 'prefix'` which has length of 6, but I would like to add empty space at the end and update it to `str = 'prefix '` with length of 7.

I have tried `str.split("").push("").join("")` but I get error saying join is not a function.
I have also tried `str[str.length] = ' '`, but this doesn't work either. What other options do I have?

Comment: You get the error because `push()` returns the new length, not the array. So you would be doing `7.join('')` and a number does not have a join method.

Comment: Why not just `str = str + ' '`?

Comment: Or string interpolation: `str = \`${str} \`;`

Comment: what is an `empty space` ? a  space is 1 character, an empty string is zero characters, so,  an `empty space` isn't a nonsens ?

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the strings:

```js
let str = 'prefix';
str = str + ' ';
// str === 'prefix '
```

or, if you want to pad any sized string to a specified length:

```
let str = 'prefix';
str = str.padEnd(7, " ");
// str === 'prefix '
```